# R: Extracting lines from dataframes in list and splitting into new dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list with 3 data frames (`DvE, DvS, EvS`) in it:

```
str(Table.list2)
List of 3
 $ DvE:'data.frame':    18482 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ gene      : Factor w/ 18482 levels "c10000_g1_i3|m.32237",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  ..$ FDR       : num [1:18482] 0.502 0.982 0.936 0.411 0.461 ...
  ..$ log2FC    : num [1:18482] 0.415 -0.245 0.728 -0.384 0.474 ...
  ..$ annotation: Factor w/ 4939 levels "","[Genbank](myosin heavy-chain) kinase [Calothrix sp. PCC 6303] ",..: 1 2204 2980 2204 1 2204 4622 2980 1 241 ...
 $ DvS:'data.frame':    18482 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ gene      : Factor w/ 18482 levels "c10000_g1_i3|m.32237",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  ..$ FDR       : num [1:18482] 1.25e-01 7.18e-01 2.02e-01 2.72e-13 6.02e-01 ...
  ..$ log2FC    : num [1:18482] -0.417 0.583 2.148 1.689 -0.167 ...
  ..$ annotation: Factor w/ 4939 levels "","[Genbank](myosin heavy-chain) kinase [Calothrix sp. PCC 6303] ",..: 1 2204 2980 2204 1 2204 4622 2980 1 241 ...
 $ EvS:'data.frame':    18482 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ gene      : Factor w/ 18482 levels "c10000_g1_i3|m.32237",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  ..$ FDR       : num [1:18482] 1.78e-03 6.04e-01 4.09e-01 3.42e-19 3.20e-02 ...
  ..$ log2FC    : num [1:18482] -0.832 0.828 1.42 2.073 -0.641 ...
  ..$ annotation: Factor w/ 4939 levels "","[Genbank](myosin heavy-chain) kinase [Calothrix sp. PCC 6303] ",..: 1 2204 2980 2204 1 2204 4622 2980 1 241 ...
```

all 3 dataframes have similar structure, e.g.:

```
> head(Table.list2$DvE)
                  gene       FDR     log2FC                               annotation
1 c10000_g1_i3|m.32237 0.5024600  0.4149066                                         
2 c10000_g1_i4|m.32240 0.9818297 -0.2449509 [Pfam]Calcium-activated chloride channel
3 c10000_g1_i4|m.32242 0.9361868  0.7277203                         [Pfam]LSM domain
4 c10000_g1_i5|m.32244 0.4114795 -0.3835745 [Pfam]Calcium-activated chloride channel
5 c10000_g1_i6|m.32245 0.4605157  0.4739777                                         
6 c10000_g1_i6|m.32246 0.4965353 -0.4607749 [Pfam]Calcium-activated chloride channel
```

What I'd like to do is in each data frame, take out data that has `FDR < 0.05` and `log2FC > 0` and put in a new data frame, and then take out data that has `FDR < 0.05` and `log2FC < 0` and put in another data frame.

So that from a list of 3 data frames, I'd get 6 new data frames that are named:

```
DvE.+

DvE.-

DvS.+

DvS.-

EvS.+

EvS.-
```

Example output of `DvE.+`:

```
                    gene          FDR    log2FC                                                                   annotation
47  c10010_g1_i4|m.32346 8.609296e-15 1.9188013                  [Genbank]conserved unknown protein [Ectocarpus siliculosus]
48  c10010_g1_i4|m.32348 5.625766e-09 1.8240089           [Genbank]hypothetical protein THAOC_07134 [Thalassiosira oceanica]
155 c10037_g1_i4|m.32582 2.666894e-02 0.6669399                                                     [Pfam]LETM1-like protein
211 c10050_g2_i2|m.32706 8.154555e-03 1.6900611 [Genbank]hypothetical protein SELMODRAFT_84252 [Selaginella moellendorffii] 
243 c10057_g1_i1|m.32812 1.936893e-02 0.8141790                                     [Pfam]Fibrinogen alpha/beta chain family
265 c10061_g4_i2|m.32861 3.614401e-02 1.7059034                                                         [Pfam]Maf1 regulator
```

I was wondering if there's a more elegant way/loop that I can do all this in rather than repeatedly writing out similar command lines?

Update:

I tried doing this:

```
DEG.list <- lapply(Table.list2, function(i){
    pos <- i[(i$FDR < 0.05 & i$log2FC > 0),]    
    neg <- i[(i$FDR < 0.05 & i$log2FC < 0),]    
    assign(paste(i, ".+", sep=""), value=pos)
    assign(paste(i, ".-", sep=""), value=neg)
})
```

But I got this error:

> Warning messages:
>       1: In assign(paste(i, ".+", sep = ""), value = pos) :
>         only the first element is used as variable name
>       2: In assign(paste(i, ".-", sep = ""), value = neg) :
>         only the first element is used as variable name
>       3: In assign(paste(i, ".+", sep = ""), value = pos) :
>         only the first element is used as variable name
>       4: In assign(paste(i, ".-", sep = ""), value = neg) :
>         only the first element is used as variable name
>       5: In assign(paste(i, ".+", sep = ""), value = pos) :
>         only the first element is used as variable name
>       6: In assign(paste(i, ".-", sep = ""), value = neg) :
>         only the first element is used as variable name

Comment: You get the error message because in your `lapply`, the variable `i` is the data frame (and not the name of the data frame). So in your assign you are trying to paste a data frame to a string. That's where the error comes from. Try this: `DEG.list <- lapply(names(Table.list2), function(i){
   pos <- Table.list2[[i]][(Table.list2[[i]]$FDR < 0.05 & Table.list2[[i]]$log2FC > 0),]    
   neg <- Table.list2[[i]][(Table.list2[[i]]$FDR < 0.05 & Table.list2[[i]]$log2FC < 0),]    
   assign(paste(i, ".+", sep=""), value=pos)
   assign(paste(i, ".-", sep=""), value=neg)
  })`

Answer (score 0):

```
   Not tested: 
   listdf<-list(DvE, DvS, EvS)
   library(dplyr) # filtering the data
  alldf<-lapply(listdf, function(i) { # Each list contains two filtered dataframes
    df1<-filter(i,FDR < 0.05 & log2FC > 0) # dfs have not been properly named here 
    df2<-filter(i,FDR < 0.05 & log2FC < 0)
    list(df1,df2)
   }
```